# Role of dummy variable in a multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-encoding

If a dummy variable is included in a model, such that $1$ is if the person has retired and $0$ if they are still working, measured over multiple time points, does this mean that the regression coefficient of the dummy variable explains the difference between two groups: the group that continues to work and the group that retires?

Or does it solely explain the difference difference pre-post (before and after retirement) when a particular group of individuals have retired?

Answer (score 0):

Before answering your question, I would like to write the purpose of dummy variable. The reason of introducing the dummy variable in any model is to bring numerical value to a category. Any model mainly works on number. Some models implicitly creates this dummy variable. So, you do not have to create dummy variable in some models(For ex: Random Forest)

To answer your question:

Bringing the dummy variable and assigning value of 0 and 1, simply means that the person is either retired or not (Your first explanation). There is no comparison on pre and post retirement. Comparison is something you imply after seeing the whole data. but dummy variable creation is just ,metaphorically, re-packaging the category variable and converting it to numerical variable.

Comment: Thanks for answering Vikas. Let me try clarifying my question. What about the regression coefficient of the dummy variable, does this reflect the group comparison or the comparison in pre/post score of those retiring?

Comment: @Barbicane : Yes, you can infer the comparison from regression coefficient. Suppose your coefficient is -5. it means that your target variable decreases by 5 when a person is retired(1) in comparison to the person who is still working(0)